# How do we handle hover event on a recipient in Outlook mail item?

Tags: outlook, vsto

Is there way to handle the hover event on a recipient in an Outlook Mail Item? I would like show a pop-up with some information about the recipient on hover and would like to know if it's possible through outlook add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since neither the [Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspector_events) nor the [Explorers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorers_events) seem to expose any events to capture the mouse over, this seems to be not possible.